How do I override the hotkey for specific sites in Chrome using StrokesPlus?
I would like to override the hotkey only for Overleaf, the online tex editor, opend in Chrome using StrokesPlus.
Specifically, on Overleaf, the default comment-out/comment-in shortcut key is Ctrl+/, but I would like to change this to Ctrl+1.
I use the code below, refered to the following posts, to override hotkey only for Chrome, but I don't know how to set up an override only for Overleaf opened in Chrome.
var fgWindow = sp.ForegroundWindow();
var exeName = fgWindow.Process.MainModule.ModuleName;

if(exeName === "chrome.exe") 
{
    sp.SendModifiedVKeys([vk.LCONTROL], [vk.OEM_2]);
} 
else
{
    sp.SendModifiedVKeys([vk.LCONTROL], [vk.VK_1]);
}

https://forum.strokesplus.net/posts/t8493-App-Specific-Shortcuts
https://forum.strokesplus.net/posts/t8245-How-to-set-hotkey-only-for-specific-application
Furthermore, the behavior of the overrided hotkey using this code is slightly different from the behavior of the default hotkey.
I would like to comment out/comment in (toggle comment) every time I press the 1 key while holding the Ctrl key.
The default hotkey  do this.
However, with the hotkey overridden in the code below, the first time I press the 1 key while holding down the Ctrl key, it comments out, but if I continue and press the 1 key one more time, 1 is entered in the editor.
Is there any way to make the overridden hotkey work like the default?
Thank you in advance.
